# Is it good/bad to pass wx from a class to a function?

Tags: python, wxpython, parameter-passing

I am quite new to OOP so this may be a very dumb question.

I have many classes which all use a common dialog that does a simple "get file" which is in my utilities module. Is it a bad practice to pass wx to that function so I don't have to have the "import wx" at the top of my utils.py file?

At the moment I am calling the routine by clicking a button and passing the default path but this means I have to have "import wx" in my utils.py as well as my test.py

test.py

```
import utils, wx

#... Lots of wx stuff happens here

f = utils.get_file(self, def_path)

#... Lots more wx stuff happens here
```

utils.py

```
import wx

def get_file(self,defaultPath):
    newFile = ''
    with wx.FileDialog(self, "Select sound file",
                       style=wx.FD_OPEN, defaultDir=defaultPath) as fileDialog:
        if fileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
            return newFile    # the user changed their mind

    # Proceed loading the file chosen by the user
    newDir = fileDialog.GetDirectory()
    if newDir == defaultPath:
        newFile = fileDialog.GetFilename()
    else:
        newFile = fileDialog.GetPath()
    return newFile
```

So, is it a bad practice to change the call to
`f = utils.get_file(self, wx, def_path)`
and the function to
`def get_file(self, wx, defaultPath):`
which allows me to remove the "import wx" from utils.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's cleaner to decouple your functions into different files. That way you only deal with return values. Assume the following two files are in the same folder:

**file_one.py**

```
import random

def get_a_number():
    return random.randint(0, 101)
```

**file_two.py**

```
from file_one import get_a_number

def multiply_random_number(random_number, multiple):
    print(random_number * multiple)

multiply_random_number(get_a_number(), 4)
```

Notice how I don't import random again in file_two. I only give the function I call there the first positional argument from file_one, which is it's return value.

Comment: I understand the concept and for plain python that works fine, however, working with wx (as in wxpython) it doesn't seem that simple. Hence why I asked if it is bad practice to pass wx as a parameter.

Comment: It's alright to pass it as a parameter as long as it works. That's the most important thing.